SELinuxで設定を変更しようとするとエラーになる
SSH接続用のポート番号をデフォルトの22番ポートから別のポート番号PORT_NUMに変更していました。そのためSELinuxで以下のコマンドを実行し、PORT_NUMでの通信を許可していました。
$ sudo semanage port --add --type ssh_port_t --proto tcp $PORT_NUM

ある日"dnf update"によるパッケージのアップデートを行った後に、SSH接続でエラーになってしまいました。systemdのログを見たところPORT_NUMで指定したポートにBindできない旨のメッセージが表示されました。
そこで一度行ったSELinuxのポート番号の確認をすると指定していたPORT_NUMが消えていました。そこで再度コマンドを実行しましたが以下のようにエラーが発生しました。
$ sudo semanage port --add --type ssh_port_t --proto tcp $PORT_NUM
libsepol.context_from_record: type samba_cert_t is not defined
libsepol.context_from_record: could not create context structure
libsepol.context_from_string: could not create context structure
libsepol.sepol_context_to_sid: could not convert system_u:object_r:samba_cert_t:s0 to sid
invalid context system_u:object_r:samba_cert_t:s0
libsemanage.semanage_validate_and_compile_fcontexts: setfiles returned error code 255.
OSError: Error

動作環境は"CentOS Stream9"です。さくらVPSを利用しており、さくらのファイアーウォールを機能させているためVPS内のfirewalldは機能させていません。
解決方法をご教示いただけませんでしょうか？

ディストリビューション固有のバグの可能性があります。質問文でディストリビューションとバージョンを明記してください。

エラーで検索するとヒットする関連しそうな Issue (Fix済み) https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=172478 / いずれにせよポート番号の変更は SELinux だけでなく、ファイアウォールや各デーモン (今回なら sshd) も設定を変更する必要があるはずなので、手順をよく確認してください。CentOS での例 https://weblabo.oscasierra.net/openssh-sshd-centos7-change-port/

ごめんなさい。かなり動作環境を引っ掻き回して掲題の件とはかけ離れた状況になりましたが解決しました。
私の結論としては以下の方法で解決しました。
fixfilex -F onboot
reboot

ただ前述の通り解決するために試行錯誤し環境をしっちゃかめっちゃかしたので概ねのオペレーションを以下に書き留めておきます。（恐らく途中他にも実行しているかと思います。）
# 新しいアップデートがあったので実行
dnf update

# 結果としてSELinuxで設定したSSHの設定が初期化されていたため再度以下実行
# 実行結果として上記エラーメッセージが出力される
sudo semanage port --add --type ssh_port_t --proto tcp $PORT_NUM

# 「SELinuxコンテキストを全て再設定すれば解決するのでは？」と思ったため安易に実行
# 結果としてログイン情報入力後、シェルを割り当てる許可がない旨表示され締め出される
fixfiles relabel

# Boot時にカーネルパラメータで"selinux=0"を追記してSELinuxを一時的に無効化して起動する

# 先のコマンドだとタイプのみコンテキストの再設定を行うため、
# -Fオプションでドメイン等コンテキスト全体を張り替える
# 再起動後無事ログインが可能
fixfiles -F onboot
reboot

# ちょっと忘れてしまいましたが、以下コマンドは再実行する必要はなく自動的に設定していたポートの再設定が行われていたと思います。
# sudo semanage port --add --type ssh_port_t --proto tcp $PORT_NUM

# ついでにDockerデーモンが起動時にエラーとなっていたため以下対処
# "/var/log/messages"に以下の出力を確認
# 再起動で復帰する旨ネットに記述あったため、再度実行
tail /var/log/messages
reboot

# 確認したところDockerデーモンの起動に成功
systemctl status docker

もし知見のある方いらっしゃれば引き続きよろしくお願いいたします。
